# Как используя PreparedStatement удалить все записи из БД, задавая batchSize?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle12c

Как используя `PreparedStatement` удалить все записи из БД, задавая `batchSize`?

В таблице около миллиона записей, нужно их удалить, используя `PreparedStatement` и задавать при этом `batchSize`. Чтобы удаление происходило частями, например, по 1000 записей, если задали `batchSize = 1000;`.

Запрос такого вида :

```
delete BpmsExtraAttributeEntityImpl EA inner join 
BpmsHistoricTaskInstanceEntityImpl HTI on EA.taskId = HTI.id inner 
join BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI on 
HTI.processInstanceId = HPI.id where HPI.endTime is null
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? LIMIT легко передаётся в prepared statement как параметр.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, как это сделать правильно, не пойму как это можно реализовать именно с удалением

Comment: Если Вы укажете СУБД, у Вас появится шанс на получение ответа...

Comment: А почему не использовать truncate?

Comment: Запрос обновил в шапке

Comment: Ну а СУБД-то, и версию, укажете? или так и будете скрывать?

Comment: Добавил описание СУБД и ее версию

Comment: А что это за запрос вы добавили, или как он может помочь понять вашу задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Если удалить нужно **все** записи (без условий), то гораздо эффективнее воспользоваться командой:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

это удаление на уровне метаданных и скорость удаления обычно не зависит от размера таблицы.

Comment: А как в этом случае выполняются операции каскадного удаления?

Comment: Нет, запрос такого вида select EA.* from BpmsExtraAttributeEntityImpl EA
inner join BpmsHistoricTaskInstanceEntityImpl HTI on EA.taskId = HTI.id
inner join BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI on HTI.processInstanceId = HPI.id
where HPI.endTime is null

Comment: @Akina, я не увидел в вопросе упоминаний о каскадном удалении или о внешних ключах.

Comment: @SergeyBekmambetov Это SELECT, a не DELETE. Показывайте лучше именно DELETE запрос - и не в комментариях, а добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Я тоже. Но я и не увидел упоминаний об отсутствии каскадных операций. А вообще - это возражение на слишком категоричное утверждение о скорости удаления, без оговорок...

Comment: Запрос обновил в шапке

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления всех записей из таблицы использовать `DELETE` не целесообразно и не рекомендуется. Тем более удалять записи по частям.

Гораздо эффективнее воспользоваться командой [TRUNCATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4).
В этом случае, использовать `PreparedStatement` нет смысла, так как за отсутствием подстановочных переменных подготавливать не для чего.

Попробуйте так:

```java
create or replace and compile java source named TestSqlExecution as
import java.sql.*;
public class TestSqlExecution {
    public static void cleanseTable (String name) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbsrv:1521/pdb1","user","pass");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();
            stmt.execute ("truncate table " + name);
            System.out.println ("cleanseTable(" + name + ") executed successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
/
create or replace procedure cleanseTable (name varchar2) as
    language java name 'TestSqlExecution.cleanseTable (java.lang.String)';
/
```

Тестовые данные и запуск:

```sql
create table tab1 as 
    select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 10e5;

exec cleanseTable ('tab1')
```

> cleanseTable(tab1) executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Для MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_by_chunks (tablename VARCHAR(64), chunk_size INT)
BEGIN
    SET @sql := CONCAT( 'DELETE FROM ',
                        tablename,
                        ' ORDER BY id LIMIT ',
                        chunk_size );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    REPEAT
        EXECUTE stmt;
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() < chunk_size END REPEAT;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dd64ed5c7a1132e3c484fb662625b14)

Запрос на удаление может быть любой сложности. Только его надо аккуратно собрать. Но непременно однотабличный - для многотабличного запроса на удаление метод не сработает, ибо там не предусмотрен LIMIT... так что из остальных таблиц данные должны удаляться каскадно по внешним ключам.

PS. Хотя fiddle работает только на версии 8+ (лень мне генерить набор данных руками), код процедуры применим и к 5+.