# Как сделать запрос DELETE более оптимальным

Tags: sql, oracle

Как сделать данный запрос более оптимальным, чтобы он выполнялся быстрее.

```
DELETE FROM BpmsExecutionEntityImpl E where exists (select HPI.* from 
BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI where HPI.id = E.processInstanceId)
and rowid in (SELECT ri FROM (select rowid ri, rownum rn from BpmsExecutionEntityImpl E where 
rownum < ${rnMax} ORDER BY E.id) WHERE rn > ${rnMin})
```

Использую СУБД Oracle 12C.

Comment: Для начала надо посмотреть план выполнения запроса (см. `explain plan`). Привести его здесь, вместе со структурой таблицы с указанием всех существующих на ней индексов

Comment: Mike, даю тебе подсказку, можно использовать команду "Merge"

Comment: Можно использовать десяток разных подходов, как с merge, так и без него. Но не видя структуры БД и текущего плана выполнения нельзя судить о эффективности того или иного метода.

Comment: А что с этим вашим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1104794/217579)? Имена таблиц показались очень знакомыми. Не стоит плодить похожие вопросы до конца не разобравшись с уже существующими.